# Javascript async function returns [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, electron-vue

`Async` function returns `[object Promise]` but desired behavior is returning real value.
I can get the value from `console.log`.

I guess it is a expected behavior of the function but I have no idea to how to fix my code.

This is in vue.js code using electron-vue and NeDB.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ testNedb3('NDId6sekw6VYLmnc')  //this is a test by adding specific id }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Promise from 'bluebird'
export default {
  methods: {
    dbFindAsync2: function (db, opt) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.find(opt, function (err, doc) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else {
            resolve(doc)
          }
        })
      })
    },
    testNedb3: async function (id) {
      const flattenMemAsync = function (arr) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
          Array.prototype.concat.apply(
            [],
            arr.map(function (arr) {
              resolve(arr.members)
            })
          )
        })
      }
      const filterByNameIdAsnc = function (arr) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
          const result = arr.filter(function (member) {
            return member.nameId === id
          })
          resolve(result)
        })
      }
      this.dbFindAsync2(
        this.$db, { 'members.nameId': id }, { 'members': 1, _id: 0 }
      ).then(function (res) {
        const docs = res
        flattenMemAsync(docs).then(function (res) {
          const flatMembers = res
          filterByNameIdAsnc(flatMembers).then(function (res) {
            console.log('result', res)
            console.log('result_firstname', res[0].firstName)
            return res
          })
        })
      })
    },
```

`this.$db` is getting data from NeDB and the data is two-dimensional array, so I am trying to flat the array by `flattenMemAsync` and remove unexpected data by `filterByNameIdAsnc`.

`console.log('result', res)` returns array and `console.log('result_firstname', res[0].firstName)` returns string.

I have changed calling code from `{{ testNedb3('NDId6sekw6VYLmnc') }}` to `{{ {{ testNedb3('NDId6sekw6VYLmnc').then(value => {return value}) }}` but the result is same.

Also changed to `{{ await testNedb3('NDId6sekw6VYLmnc').then(value => {return value}) }}` but I got error "Parsing error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function.".

Any comment can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't call an async method within a view.

When you mark the method as async it will return a promise, so, its pointless to return a promise and mark it as async at same time.

You should await the async method or promise from [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) or some other suitable [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) and save the result in component’s data, then render that data.

Also, take a look at [vue-promised](https://github.com/posva/vue-promised) plugin.